Disadvantages of using void * to hold generic objects?
I'm a C beginner, and I've got a question while I read the Chapter 19.5 of C Programming: A Modern Approach (2nd Edition) by K. N. King.
In this chapter, the author explains what is program design and demonstrates the related concepts about it by developing an implementation of the stack data structure.
The below code is the part of the implementation:
typedef int Item;

void push(Stack s, Item i);

Since the Item type has been defined as int, currently the stack is not able to have items of different types except int.
Because of this flaw, the author introduces a way to make this stack generic:
void push(Stack s, void *p);

The way is the use of void *. As far as I understand, This allows the stack to have arbitrary pointers, i.e. various types.
After the introduction of void *, the author mentions the following which I don't understand:

There are two disadvantages to using void * as the item type. One is that this approach doesn't work for data that can't be represented in pointer form. Items could be strings (which are represented by a pointer to the first character in the string) or dynamically allocated structures but not basic types such as int and double.
p. 503, Chapter 19.5 Design Issues for Abstract Data Types

Question 1: What data can't be represented in pointer form? I don't think there is such data. The reason I think so is, int * is a pointer to an int object, struct foo * is a pointer to a struct foo object, and int (*)(int, char **) is the pointer to the well-known main function.
Question 2: Actually, I don't guess the intent of the author giving strings and dynamically allocated structures as examples of such data. As far as I'm concerned, I agree that it would be problematic if a string were not ended with \0, since I need to know the length of the string in order to give it a proper manipulation. Meanwhile, if only a string were null-terminated, wouldn't it be okay to push the string, i.e. char * to the stack? What makes me more confusing is the case of dynamically allocated structures. I think that a dynamically allocated structure is just an object like any other types. So, if only I remembered what objects I've pushed to the stack, wouldn't it be okay to pop an item from the stack and to type-cast it to the proper type in order to dereference it? Of course, it is needless to say that remembering types of pushed items is not confined to dynamically allocated structures, since the stack takes void *. For instance, I think that if I pushed a int object to the stack, type-casting is necessary to dereference it: value = *((int *) pop(stack)) .
Question 3: This question is not (directly?) related to this post. However, I think it is a nice timing to ask, so I ask: In the Chapter 17, the author says:

In general, we can assign a void * value to a variable of any pointer type and vice versa.
p. 416, Chapter 17.2

However, I read some sentences from the Suggested Improvements section in the website of this book:

Actually, this is only true for pointers to object/data types; pointers to functions cannot reliably be converted to void pointers or vice versa in ISO C (they can in POSIX).
...
dereferencing a void pointer is only valid in a void context and essentially useless...
Rob Gamble

Since I'm not only a C beginner as I've mentioned early, I'm also a computer beginner. From this reason, I'm curious: why function pointers can't (reliably?) be converted to void pointers and vice versa? (I searched for it and found a post addressing this question, but the answers are, I'm afraid, somewhat difficult for me to understand) Also, I don't understand what the meaning of void context.
Thank you for taking your golden time to read this question. It would be greatly appreciated if you should give me some enlightenment.

I think the author means that some data are too large to fit in a void *. For example, if the sizeof a void pointer is 8 bytes, trying to store some data larger that 8 bytes will be a problem. Storing a pointer to the data should be ok - but trying to put the data itself in a void * might be an issue. It depends on what is going on inside of push.

push(s, 3.141592653589793238)

The main thing to be aware of is the lifetime of the objects being pointed to. For example if a called function pushes a pointer to a variable with automatic storage duration, that pointer will become invalid once the function returns (or leaves the block where the variable is defined). So dereferencing the pointer subsequently would lead to UB. Also, if pushing pointers to mixture of dynamically allocated and non-dynamically allocated objects, some code would need to keep track of which pointers point to dynamically allocated storage, and which pointers do not.

There is no guarantee that a pointer is at least as big as any integer or floating point type.

Thank you for kind replies. Jeez, I've never ever thought of putting a int or something into a pointer variable.


Question 1: What data can't be represented in pointer form? I don't think there is such data.

If the text means "data you can't point at", then I don't think so either. A void* can either be converted to any other object pointer or alternatively get set to point to the address of any pointer object.
The only thing you can't do is to assign a function pointer to a void*.
In case the author means that we should store the representation of objects inside a void* then that's a horrible idea. It is only possible to do that for integer types of smaller or equal size as the void* anyway, so it is far from generic. And even then there's restrictions with alignment and so on.


Question 2:


if only a string were null-terminated, wouldn't it be okay to push the string, i.e. char * to the stack?

That's fine.

I think that a dynamically allocated structure is just an object like any other types

There's no difference regarding where the data is allocated. Either the stack makes a copy of it or otherwise keep a pointer to it.
It should be mentioned that best practices when writing any form of "abstact data type" (ADT) such as a stack, is to always make a copy of the data to be handled and allocated internally by the stack. And not to store pointers to data allocated elsewhere, as that will be bug-prone and hard to maintain.


Question 3


I'm curious: why function pointers can't (reliably?) be converted to void pointers and vice versa?

Because such behavior isn't defined by the C standard. The chapter 6.3.2.3 either explicitly speaks of object pointers, as it does in every scenario where the behavior of void* is defined, or it explicitly speaks of function pointers in a section of its own.
Notably, the parts regarding conversions between integers to/from pointers or null pointers to/from pointers apply to both object pointers and function pointers.
Furthermore most conversions sort under the rules of assignment 6.5.16.1, where the rule regarding void pointers is as follows (emphasis mine):


the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) one operand is a pointer to an object type, and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;


The above is a formal constraint, meaning that the C compiler must implement it strictly and give the programmer a diagnostic message in case the code does not conform to C language constraints. A compiler which fails to give a diagnostic message is not conforming to the C standard.
Regarding hardware:
The C standard aside, CPUs come in two flavours: Harvard architecture, which (simply put) accesses data and code on separate buses, and von Neumann architechture, which (simply put) can access either data or code memory through the same bus. On Harvard architectures in particular it might be deeply problematic to assign data pointers to function pointers or vice versa, because the CPU can't handle that without using diverse tricks.
But also on any CPU architecture which uses a somewhat advanced memory mapping unit (MMU), it may keep track on what parts of the memory that is data and which parts are code, and then throw a hardware exception if you attempt to run code from data memory or use code memory for data storage. Such exceptions might be thrown as early as at the point of conversion and not necessarily just when you de-reference an object pointer or call a function pointer.
And finally the data address format is not necessarily compatible with the code address format. It is not uncommon to have systems where data is stored in one memory area, but (parts of) the code are stored in an expanded memory area beyond the normal bus range. For example on some system data pointers could be guaranteed to always be 16 bits but function pointers could be up to 24 bits. Stuff like this is very common in low end 8/16 bit microcontrollers.
Data and code might also have different alignment requirements. As in a CPU may be able to read data which is either 16 or 32 bit aligned, but it requires all functions to be 32 bit aligned in terms of start address.

Re “deeply problematic to assign data pointers to function pointers or vice versa”: A Harvard architecture prevents using accessing a function as data or vice-versa. It has no effect on assigning or converting pointers of one type to another. You could not assign a pointer to a function to a pointer to char and then use it to read the instructions of the function, but you could (as far as the architecture is concerned, not the C implementation) convert it to a pointer to char, store it, read it back, convert it back to a pointer to a function, and use it to call the function.

Thank you for the detailed explanations. I'm glad to get to know new things.

By the way, do you mind if I ask you about "pointer alignment" you mentioned at the top of this answer? I've heard of this word before somewhere, but I don't seem to know what it is.

@DoohyeonWon When you convert from an integer to a pointer, the address must be evenly divisible with the alignment of the pointed-at type. Otherwise the whole program might crash when accessing it, since some CPUs can't read misaligned data, while other CPUs produce slower code when reading misaligned. Breaking alignment requirements of the target (if they exist) by using a cast invokes undefined behavior.


Question 1: What data can't be represented in pointer form?

The text in the book, “There are two disadvantages to using void * as the item type. One is that this approach doesn't work for data that can't be represented in pointer form.”, is poorly stated. The author means literally representing the value of some type, say double, in a pointer, not using a pointer to point to the data. That is, the pointer value itself encodes the data.
Now, you can convert an int to void * using a cast, but the C standard does not guarantee that converting the resulting void * back to int will produce the original value. Casting a double to void * is a constraint violation (C 2018 6.5.4 4), but you could use memcpy to copy the bytes of a double into a void *, but only if a void * has as many bytes as a double, which is not always the case. Additionally, a pointer could have multiple representations, so that void *a = b; might produce different bytes in the void * that is a than are in the original void * that is b as long as those bytes represent the same pointer value. So, even if you did copy the bytes of an int or a double into void *, they would not necessarily be preserved.
When the author speaks of strings or pointers to dynamically allocated structures being suitable items for this, they are again stating it poorly. Here, a void * does not represent a string or a structure, it points to it. And a void * could just as easily point to a statically or automatically allocated structure, not just a dynamically allocated one. And it can point to an int or double as well.

Question 3:  the author says:

In general, we can assign a void * value to a variable of any pointer type and vice versa.
…


[From another source] Actually, this is only true for pointers to object/data types; pointers to functions cannot reliably be converted to void pointers or vice versa in ISO C (they can in POSIX).


The latter is correct. The C standard does not define conversion a pointer to a function to a pointer to an object type or vice-versa. It does not prohibit it; it merely does not define it. C implementations are free to extended the standard by defining it, which is why you can do this in POSIX.

I appreciate your kind explanations. It clarifies a lot of my curiosity.

Meanwhile, If you don't mind, I would like to ask a one more question. To be honest, I don't seem to understand this sentence from your answer: "a pointer could have multiple representations." Do you mean things like a near/far pointer? I've heard of these words but I'm not sure what it is.

@DoohyeonWon: Some systems have used base-and-offset methods of addressing, where an address would be formed from a base number b and an offset o, and the physical address would be 64•b+o, or a similar formula. In a system like this, the address formed by base 100 and offset 23 would be 64•100+23=6423. But the address formed by base 97 and offset 215 would be the same, 64•97+215=6423. So the same address has multiple representations.

Using a void* stack for ints like:
int value = 13;
int* x = (int*) malloc(sizeof(x[0]));
*x = value;
push(stack, x);
int* y = (int*) stack.pop();
value = *y;
free(y);

would really be too painful with respect to memory allocation, typing, efficiency and conciseness.
However you could create your own int stack using a pointer stack.
NUL terminated strings have been called a historical error be the C author(s) themselve, even rising to processor  instructions. A Pascal string/array may have a preceding size, so bounds checking can be done.
Function pointers are addresses of executable code, and might not point to data memory where variables are stored. It should not be execute-only, and forget about memcpy copying to code.
As you are a beginner: C is not a high level language, more a dirty (w.r.t. safety, programming principles) tool language. I am sure you will like the language as I do. But you should look for really high level languages too. In C everything seems to be a pointer, in Pascal you might pass to a function an array as actual bytes on the stack.
You should be aware that C is nicely low-level for being close to the architecture, computing notions. At the same time it is messy in handling computing concepts. A language for learning computer science/programming it is not.

The (int*) casts are not needed in C.   malloc(sizeof x[0]) is easier to code right, review and maintain than malloc(sizeof(int)). IAC, if the use of OP's functions are too complex, as attempted to show here, then the interface needs change, not certainly the language.

Indeed sizeof x[0] though mixed * / [] style here. I wanted at that point to show that an int stack using void pointers is unworkable. On the language C (I like) if K&R would have created a car, it would not necessarily have airbags, fuel indicator, breaks, headlights. That can be fine (offroad) but requires quality.

I appreciate your great advice. It helps me a lot. Actually, recently I have an interest in Haskell. But in my opinion, it seems not easy to learn unless a learner has a good command of logic/math. Unfortunately I do not; therefore it is not easy for me to learn it. Q.E.D.

Haskell is really great though. There are more difficult functional languages. Good luck with programming.

Question 1, 2:
I think the author would like to say that the following is forbidden:
void f(Stack *s) {
    int i;
    s.push(&i);
}

More deeper that using pointers is "dangerous" and necessitate a lot of care, even with dynamically allocated data: who is the proprietary of the data pointed? i.e. is it on responsability of the stack to free the memory when poping? Or?
Think of something like:
T *data = malloc(sizeof T); // whatever T is
s.push(data); // Now who own the pointed data?
free(data); // oups

Question 3:
Casting function pointer to void * is not addressed by the C standard, that's all. The main reason is that in the C point-of-view functions are not data, and that pointing to a function may require a very different scheme than pointing to data. That is the way C lawyers defined the language: to be supported on many different (possibly exotic) platforms.
POSIX has another view on the subject. POSIX concerns is different. POSIX tackles the problem of POSIX platform compliance, and then says that on such a platform function pointers can be safely converted to and back to void *.
That means that such a code can only be safely used on POSIX platforms (or platforms that also permit it).

Also in C++, combining new and free is a severe bug. Please keep the language to the one used in the question though.

Jean-Baptiste Yunès, "The main reason is that in the C point-of-view functions are not data, and that pointing to a function may require a very different scheme than pointing to data." --> Hmmm, I thought a key reason was that void * may be too small for a function pointer.  They do not have to be the same size.

@chux-ReinstateMonica Isn't it what I said: pointing to a function may require a very different scheme than pointing to data. Note that function pointers also does not support pointer arithmetic, for the same reason: a function has no size.

@4386427 corrected.

Re “Casting function pointer to void * is forbidden by the C standard, that's all”: The C standard does not forbid casting a function pointer to void *. The constraints for the cast operator do not forbid it. No sentence in the standard forbids it. The C standard merely does not define what happens when a program does it. If it were forbidden, POSIX could not support it and conform to the C standard, but POSIX does support it and does conform to the C standard in this regard. It is allowed but not defined.

Thank you for giving me a nice explanation and a new perspective. It resolves my curiosity.

@EricPostpischil Right!


Question 1: What data can't be represented in pointer form?

Numeric literals; when Item was defined as an int, you could push literal values onto the stack like
push( s, 10 );

If Item is a void *, this won't work; you'd have to create an object, assign a value to it, and take its address:
int x = 10;
push( s, &x );

double y = 3.14;
push( s, &y );

but there's another problem; you can't use the same variable multiple times.  You can't do something like
int x = 10;
push( s, &x );
x = 15;
push( s, &x );
x = 30;
push( s, &x );

because all those entries point to the same variable, and it only stores the last thing you assigned to it.  You basically have this situation:
   +---+          +----+
s: |   | --+-> x: | 30 |
   +---+   |      +----+
   |   | --+
   +---+   |
   |   | --+
   +---+

IOW, your stack doesn't contain {30, 15, 10}, it contains {&x, &x, &x} and x == 30.
Event worse, if you leave x's scope, suddenly all those pointers become invalid; the object they were pointing to no longer exists.
You'd have to create a new object for each item you want to push, and you have to make sure that object persists beyond any particular function's lifetime, meaning you have to use dynamic allocation:
int *x = malloc( sizeof *x ); // creates an int object
*x = 10;
push( s, x );
x = malloc( sizeof *x ); // creates a *new* int object
*x = 15;
push( s, x );
x = malloc( sizeof *x ); // creates *another* new int object
*x = 30;
push( s, x );

although you wouldn't write it that clumsily.  You could write a type-aware front end that handles that operation, like
/**
 * You can't push the address of val directly as in
 * 
 *    push( s, &val );
 *
 * because a) you wind up pushing the same address
 * every time, and b) val ceases to exist once you 
 * exit the function.  You *have* to create a new
 * object via malloc for each item you want to push.
 */
void push_int( Stack s, int val )
{
  int *item = malloc( sizeof *item );
  *item = val;
  push( s, item );
}

void push_double( Stack s, double val )
{
  double *item = malloc( sizeof *item );
  *item = val;
  push( s, item );
}

You could use _Generic to abstract that away:
#define PUSH(s, x) _Generic((x),          \
                       int : push_int,    \
                    double : push_double  \
                   )(s, x)

and use
PUSH( s, 10 );
PUSH( s, 3.1415 );

Yeah, it's a pain in the ass.  C simply wasn't designed with generic programming in mind.  This is why newer languages like C++ and Java and C# provide high-level support for type-agnostic code (templates, generics, etc.).
You'll have to make sure you free that memory when you pop it off the stack.

Question 2: Actually, I don't guess the intent of the author giving strings and dynamically allocated structures as examples of such data.

See above.  We're dynamically creating objects and storing the pointers to them.
Strings are stored in arrays of character type; under most circumstances array expressions "decay" to pointers, so most of the time when you're dealing with strings you're dealing with expressions of type char *.  This would work:
push( s, "foo" );
push( s, "bar" );
push( s, "bletch" );

because each string literal expression "decays" to a pointer to the first element, and each literal is stored at a different address.  However, the following code has the exact same problem shown above:
char str[20];
strcpy( str, "foo" );
push( s, str );
strcpy( str, "bar" );
push( s, str );
strcpy( str, "bletch" );
push( s, str );

because we've pushed the address of the same object multiple times, so all those items point to the same thing.

Question 3: why function pointers can't (reliably?) be converted to void pointers and vice versa?

Most simply, because void is an object type1 and functions are not objects.  There are platforms out there that use completely different representations for function vs. object pointers such that the conversion would be "lossy" (such as if a function pointer stored additional metadata that's lost in the conversion to void *) and you can't get the original pointer value back, or that the conversion would result in a trap value that causes the program to crash if you try to use it.
Sort of like casting a float to an int and back again; if any of the original value was fractional, it's now lost.



Even though you can't actually create a void object.



Thank you for your kind and detailed explanations. It lightens my curiosities.

By the way, if you don't mind, may I ask you a one more question? Do you think it is a good idea to check the return value of malloc() whenever I use it? Actually, not just malloc, I think there are a lot functions from the standard library which return something to indicate whether the call to the function was okay. However, if I checked the return values manually with if statement like if (ptr = malloc() == NULL), then the number of lines of the code increases shortly after and the readability seems not good.

@DoohyeonWon: Yes, you should check the result of malloc; I left those checks out just to keep the examples smaller.  You should also get in the habit of checking the result of scanf and fscanf.
